# How to load a model checkpoint with pytorch-lightning?

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I am am building a model the following way:

```
class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, backbone, loss_module, lr):
        super().__init__()
        self.backbone = backbone
        self.backbone.classifier = nn.Linear(1024, 2)
        self.loss_module = loss_module
        self.lr = lr
        self.save_hyperparameters()
```

I am initializing the backbone with pretrained weights like this:

```
backbone = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'densenet121', weights='DenseNet121_Weights.DEFAULT')
lr = 0.01
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
model = MyModel(backbone, loss, lr)
```

When training, this gives the following warning: Attribute 'model' is an instance of `nn.Module` and is already saved during checkpointing. It is recommended to ignore them using `self.save_hyperparameters(ignore=['backbone'])`. Same warning for the loss function.
Since the weights are saved during checkpointing I changed my code according to the recommendation.
Trying to load a model checkpoint with `MyModel.load_from_checkpoint(path_to_checkpoint)` gives this error: missing 2 required positional arguments: 'backbone' and 'loss_module'.

I noticed that there is no problem with the learning rate parameter since it's value is stored in the .yaml file. I think the solution would be to move the backbone and loss function initialization inside the **init**() function. But wouldn't that mean the backbone weights get reinitialized every time I load a checkpoint?